# Groups without factorization

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-combinatorics, computational-group-theory

A group G is said to have a *factorization* if there exist proper subgroups $A$ and $B$ such that $G = AB = \{ ab \  | \  a \in A, b \in B \}$.

The paper [Factorisations of sporadic simple groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2006.04.019) (by Michael Giudici) provides the classification of all the factorizations of the sporadic simple groups. We observe there that only $11$ sporadic simple groups (among $26$) admit a factorization. So the remaining $15$ (which are $J_1$, $M_{22}$, $J_3$, $McL$, $O'N$, $Co_3$, $Co_2$, $F_5$, $Ly$, $F_3$, $Fi_{23}$, $J_4$, $F_{3+}$, $F_2$, $F_1$) admit no factorization.

Obviously, a cyclic group admits no factorization if and only if it is of prime power order.

**Question**: What are all the (other) finite groups without factorization?
(Is there an *official* name for such a group?)

*Proposition*: Let $G$ be a group without factorization. If the intersection of all the maximal subgroups of $G$ is the trivial subgroup then $G$ is simple.
*proof*: Assume $G$ non-simple and let $N$ be a non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $G$. If every maximal subgroup of $G$ contains $N$ then their intersection also, which contradicts the assumption. So there is a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$  not containing $N$. It follows that $NM=G$, contradiction. $\square$

*Sub-question*: must a non-simple finite group without factorization be cyclic (of prime power order)?

*Lemma*: A finite group $G$ admits a unique maximal subgroup $M$ iff it is cyclic of prime power order.
*proof*:  Let $g \in G \setminus M$ and $H = \langle g \rangle$. If $H \neq G$ then there must exist a maximal subgroup $M'$ of $G$ containing $H$, but $M=M'$ by assumption, so $g \in M$, contradiction. So $G = H$ is cyclic. It is moreover of prime power order by Chinese Remainder Theorem. $\square$

*Bonus question*: What do we know about the infinite groups without factorization?

Comment: I think it's called "factorization" for advertising purposes: I don't think even partly reduces the understanding of the group to simpler subgroups (and hence I wouldn't call "prime" such a marginal notion). Also note that a group without factorization $AB$ might have a (nontrivial) factorization $ABC$. (Actually, for every finite group $G$ that is not cyclic of prime power order, there exists $n$ and proper subgroups $G_1,\dots,G_n$ such that $G=G_1G_2\dots G_n$.)

Comment: Z/p^nZ is also "non factorizable"

Comment: @MarcoFarinati: Yes. I improved the post.

Comment: Finite groups $G$ with $|G|=p^n$ (up to cyclic groups) and $|G|=p^nq^m$ have a factorization ($p,q$ distinct primes). So for groups without factorization you have to look at groups those order has at least three distinct prime divisors.

Comment: More generally: Let $|G|=nm$ with coprime $n,m>1$. If $G$ has subgroups of orders $n,m$ then $G$ has a factorization.

Comment: For (finite) solvable groups you can always use Hall subgroups to find a factorization.

Comment: @j.p. except precisely those cyclic groups of prime-power order.

Comment: Sub-question: clearly if $G$ is a perfect finite group with center $Z$ and $G/Z$ simple "without factorization", then $G$ is also "without factorization".

Comment: Tarski Monsters give examples of infinite groups without factorizations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This must be "well-known": If we have $G = AB$ when $G$ is a finite group, and $A,B$ are proper subgroups of $G$, then we may suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both maximal.

For if $A$ is not maximal, and $A < C$ with $C$ maximal, then we still have $G = CB,$ and $B \not \leq C$, so we may replace $A$ by $C$ and assume that $A$ is maximal.

Now if $B$ is not maximal, but $B < D$ with $D$ maximal, then we have $G = AD$ and $A,D$ are both proper and maximal, so we can replace $B$ by $D$ and assume, $A,B$ are both maximal.

Hence the finite group $G$ has no factorization if and only if $|AB| < |G|$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are maximal subgroups of $G$, ie if and only if $[G:A] > [B:A \cap B]$ whenever $A,B$ are maximal subgroups of $G$.

In particular, since the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ is the intersection of the maximal subgroups of $G$ we conclude that $G$ has a factorization if and only if $G/\Phi(G)$ has a factorization.

Since $G/\Phi(G)$ has trivial Frattini subgroup, we conclude from the argument you gave in the question, that if $G$ has no factorization, then $G/\Phi(G)$ is a simple group.

Later edit: By the way, this answers the subquestion in the negative. If we take a nonsplit extension $H$ of a non-Abelian finite simple group $G$ which itself has no factorization by a finite irreducible $G$-module $M$, then we obtain a non-simple finite group $H$ which is neither simple nor cyclic of prime-power order, yet there is is no factorization of $H$ (and there are examples of such non-split extensions- note that $\Phi(H) = M$ in that case. For example, $J_{3}$ admits no factorization, and it has a (non-split) triple cover which also admits no factorization).

Even later edit: In fact, we can now further restrict all finite groups $G$ which admit no factorization. By a slight extension of the argument above, we deduce that $G$ has no factorization if and only if $G/X$ has no factorization whenever $X \lhd G$ with $X \leq \Phi(G)$.

If G has no factorization, we know that $G/\Phi(G)$ is a simple group without a factorization.

If $G/\Phi(G)$ is cyclic of prime order, then $G$ is cyclic, and $G$ must be a cyclic $p$-group for some prime $p$.

If $G/\Phi(G)$ is non-Abelian simple, then we may take $X \lhd G$ with 
$X < \Phi(G)$ and $[\Phi(G):X]$ minimal. Let $V = \Phi(G)/X.$

Then $V = \Phi(G/X)$ and $G/X$ is a non-split extension of the simple group $G/\Phi(G)$ by the irreducible $G/\Phi(G)$-module $V.$

Hence the finite group $G$ admits no factorization if and only if either $G$ is cyclic of prime power order or else $G/\Phi(G)$ is a non-Abelian simple group with no factorization which admits a non-split extension by a finite 
(possibly trivial) irreducible $G/\Phi(G)$-module $V$ occurring as a "top" $G$-chief factor within $\Phi(G)$ (that is to say $V$ occurs as $\Phi(G)/X$ where $X$ is maximal subject to being normal in $G$ and properly contained in $\Phi(G)$).

Comment: After your answer, we are reduced "in some sense" to classify the finite simple groups without factorization. Is there a non-abelian and non-sporadic finite simple group without factorization? If so, what are there?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Have you tried looking for an answer in the AMS memoir by Liebeck, Praeger, and Saxl? As Geoff notes in his answer, clearly it suffices to check when there is a factorization into a product of two maximal subgroups. And Liebeck-Praeger-Saxl classify these factorizations.

Comment: As @spin says, the simple groups which admit no factorisation are classified by Liebeck-Praeger-Saxl. There is also the question about which of these admit a non-split extension by an irreducible (finite, possibly trivial) irreducible  module $V$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I am not sure how to read the tables in this book. For example, $M_{22}$ appears in Table 6 (page 15) whereas it does not appear in the paper of Michael Giudici cited above.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: The notation is explained in the book. Let $L = M_{22}$. The entry of $L$ in Table 6 is marked with (*) and it is stated that $G = L.2 = \operatorname{Aut}(L)$. We have $G = AB$ but $L \neq (L \cap A)(L \cap B)$ in this particular case, which is proven in 6.3 in the book

Answer (score 4):

The smallest non-abelian group without factorization is simple of order $1092$: it is $A_1(13)$.

Using the answer of Geoff and by browsing the book [The maximal factorizations of the finite simple groups and their automorphism groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1016353) (by Martin W. Liebeck, Cheryl E. Praeger and Jan Saxl), the finite simple groups without factorization are the following:

- Every cyclic group of prime order.
- Alternating: none
- Chevalley groups: $A_n(q)$ with $n=1$, $q \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$ and $q\neq 5,9,29$, or with $n \ge 2$ even and $(n+1) | (q-1)$; $E_6(q)$; $E_7(q)$; $E_8(q)$; $F_4(q)$ with $q \neq 2^n$; $G_2(q) $ with  $q>4 $ and $q \neq 3^n$.
- Twisted Chevalley groups: $^2A_{2n}(q^2)$ except $(n,q) = (1,3),(1,5),(4,2)$; $^2B_2(2^{2n+1})$; $^2D_{2n}(q^2)$; $^3D_4(q^3)$; $^2E_6(q^2)$; $^2F_4(2^{2n+1})$; $^2G_2(3^{2n+1})$.
- Sporadic: $J_1$, $M_{22}$, $J_3$, $McL$, $O'N$, $Co_3$, $Co_2$, $F_5$, $Ly$, $F_3$, $Fi_{23}$, $J_4$, $F_{3+}$, $F_2$, $F_1$.

*Before any use*: this list requires a double checking.